# 2 Dimentional array dereferencing ,how to evaluate through pointers

Tags: pointers, multidimensional-array

```
a[2][3] = {{-3,14,5},{1,-10,8}}

*(a[j]+k) 
*(a[j+k-2]) 
(*(a+j))[k]) 

(*(a+k-1))[j] 
*((*(a+j))+k)) 

(**(a+j)+k) 
*(&a[0][0]+j+k)
```

when i printf these i get
Output:
8
1
8
-10
8
3
1
respectively
Please if anyone can explain in detail how the values are coming ,i am a new starter please pardon me for bad formatting here and also bothering you for with so much work :)

Comment: I don't understand what you've posted. Can you please explain what you're asking?

Comment: I tried to format your code a bit better. I hope I preserved the intended meaning. Please let me know if my replace the `________` was incorrect, or revert the edit.

Comment: @paulPRo thankyou yes you did a good job

Comment: @Gabe when i printf 7 expressions these values come ,how that values are coming i want to ask you guys

Comment: @iyer yes its a trick question.. please explain how these values are coming

Comment: @Gabe now I have edited the question,do you understand what i am asking now?

Answer (score 0):

I assume j == 1 and k == 2:

```
*(a[j]+k) == *(a[1]+2) :

    a[1] = {1, -10, 8};
    So a[1]+2 is a pointer to 8, and *(a[1]+2) == 8
```

```
*(a[j+k-2]) == *(a[1+2-2]) == *(a[1]):

    a[1] = {1, -10, 8}
    Since *a[1] is the value of the first element in a[1], the expression evaluates to 1
```

```
(*(a+j))[k] == (*(a+1))[2]:

    a+1 is a pointer to the second element in a, so *(a+1) == a[1] = {1, -10, 8}
    a[1][2] == 8
```

```
(*(a+k-1))[j]  == (*(a+2-1))[1] == (*(a+1))[1]:

    *(a+1) == a[1] (see the last answer)
    a[1][1] == -10
```

```
*((*(a+j))+k) == *((*(a+1))+2):

     *(a+1) == a[1], so the expressions is equivalent to *(a[1]+2)
     *(a[1]+2) is equivalent to a[1][2] for the same reasoning as above, which is 8
```

```
(**(a+j)+k)  == (**(a+1)+2):

    *(a+1) = a[1]
   **(a+1) = a[1][0] == 1
     Adding 2 to that gives 3
```

```
*(&a[0][0]+j+k) == *(&a[0][0]+1+2) == *(&a[0][0]+3):

    &a[0][0] == a[0]
    *(a[0]+3) == a[0][3];
```

This last one is returning 1, because it is extending in memory past the end of a[0] into a[1], and you're getting a[1][0]. I think this behavior is actually undefined though. It depends on whether the C standard guarantees that an initialized 2D array will be allocated sequentially in memory or not, and could result in a Segmentation fault or worse.

Comment: there could have been no better answer wonderfully explained thanyou very much ,keep up the good work :))

Comment: I totally can see that you are a Pro but consider this ,from what you have told me
int a[b][c];

value of a[d][e]  such that d<b ,e<c is always evaluated as *(a+d*c+e)

so in our original question accidentlly  

a[0][3]=*(a+0*3+3) =*(a+3).............equation A

a[1][0]=*(a+1*3+0)=*(a+3)..............equation B

coming the same... if in the declaration of the array it was int a[2][4] instead of int[2][3]

the equation A and Equation B will give different answers and thus ,Every thing looks Well 

defined in C  , please tell me if i am wrong... thankyou PaulPro

Comment: ^^^ Sorry for the replying in comment my reputation is low cant answer to my own question